# Will Rift Beta Characters persist after launch?

Tags: rift

I know that different MMOs with different Betas have done different things regarding beta characters.

For Rift in particular, the beta characters have persisted across the 6 betas -- will these characters persist after launch? Only for a privileged subset of players? (such as pre-orders / collector's editions, etc.)

Personally, I'm not optimistic, however I haven't yet found any official word from Tirion, so I thought I'd toss this out here.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a case of a game launch where they *kept* the beta characters. It seems rather counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this FAQ](http://forums.riftgame.com/showthread.php?19289-Rift-Pre-Order-FAQ-UPDATED-1-20-11)

> Will our closed-beta characters be
>   wiped for the Head Start and launch of
>   RIFT? Yes